# How to use ManagedObjectContext in non View Swift file

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I use standard approach for injection of CoreData ManagedObjectContect from App struct

```
WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
    }
```

to all my views via wrapper

```
 @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
```

and it works fine.
I'd like to create class with methods handling CoreData objects in the same context but @Environment wrapper used as above doesn't work in non SfiftUI file.
What is recommended approach here to handle CoreData?

Comment: Pass a reference to `persistenceController.container.viewContext` to whatever class or function needs it explicitly (ie not using `.environment`)

Comment: I did this but then data changes made by class methods are not automatically recognized by views. If I reload app again data are changed. Perphaps I should do class conform to ObservableObjects?

Comment: I'm not saying *instead of* -- I mean in *addition to*. In other words, keep using `.environment` for your `View`s, and in the event that you need to pass it to something that isn't a view, use a reference passed to it explicitly.

Comment: I kept all my .environment there. Well, actually it relates to the method below which is obviously executed because data are deleted when I reload app but immediately after method execution view is still showing data
private func deleteAllRates() async {
     let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Rates")
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)
    do {
        try viewContext.execute(deleteRequest)
        try viewContext.save()} catch let error {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
    }}

Comment: All coredata objects are observable objects make sure they are wrapped in `@ObservedObject` in the View and you need to use `@FetchRequest` or `NSFetchedRequestController`. `NSFetchRequest` does not observe the store.

Comment: Thanks it helped. Issue was with NSBatchDeleteRequest